# In ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor, how do you get the value (text) of @Html.Label?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm sorry I've tried searching but I didnt receive any information related to my problem.

My view:

```
<legend>COMFIRM</legend>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdminDeleteResult", "Admin",
                            new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div" }))
    {
        <div id="div"></div>
        <h6>ARE YOU SURE WANT TO DELETE</h6>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("User ID:")
                @Html.Label("userid", Model.userid)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("Username:")
                @Html.Label(Model.username)
            </li>
        </ol>
        <button>DELETE</button>
    }
</fieldset>
```

And my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AdminDeleteResult(FormCollection form)
{
     string userid = form["userid"].ToString(); //ERROR HERE
     ...
}
```

I've try to replace Label by `@Html.TextBox("userid")` and it works fine.
But I want to use Label because I dont want people change it's value.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's `@Html.Display("username")` or better `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.username)`. Note you do not want a 'Label' (a `<label>` tag is a html element associated with a form control - clicking on it sets focus to the associated control.

Comment: You need to start using ViewModels, if you bind your view to a ViewModel , then you can simply get any value that you bind in to your view

Comment: iman nemati  of course, I used @model <myProjectName>.Models.UserModel

Comment: @NoobFromMars He wanted to advice you to use that model in the action too.

Comment: sorry, i mean use your Model properly in your Action method to get the value you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not the purpose of the `Label` you have to use an `input`. The purpose of the `form` is to collect data, and the data are kept in *form elements*.

If you don't want people to change the value (this can be discussed), you can make the `input` `readonly` or you can hide it.

Because your View make use of a *Model* you can use HtmlHelpers with lambda expression to create your  form.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdminDeleteResult", "Admin",
                        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div" }))
{
    <div id="div"></div>
    <h6>ARE YOU SURE WANT TO DELETE</h6>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.Label(model => model.userid)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.userid, new { @readonly="readonly" })

            @* @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.userid) *@
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.Label(model => model.username)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.username, new { @readonly="readonly" }) 
        </li>
    </ol>
    <button>DELETE</button>
}
```

As @man-nemati mentioned, it's better to use the model in your action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AdminDeleteResult(UserModel user)
{
   string userid =user.userid; // userid is storred in user
   // ...
}
```